# Flight connection time reduced after booking

Tags: short-connections, air-india

I booked a flight with connection time between two flight as 1:40 Hr.

However, Now when I see the flight schedule, it's been reduced to 0:40 hr which I think isn't sufficient enough for transfer.

Note: Flight booking sites have stopped showing this flight schedule.

My Itinerary details which I received upon booking is like this:

`Air India 111  XXXX (XXX)
11:15am Terminal: 2 flight to YYY(YYY)
5:00pm Terminal: 3 Cabin: Economy / Coach (L)
9h 15m duration`

`1h 40m stop YYY (YYY)`

`Air India 112 YYY (YYY)
6:40pm Terminal: 3 flight to ZZZ (ZZZ)
8:15pm
Cabin: Economy / Coach (V)
1h 35m duration`

However now the flight schedule has changed to this

`Air India 111  XXXX (XXX)
11:30am Terminal: 2 flight to YYY(YYY)
6:00pm Terminal: 3 Cabin: Economy / Coach (L)
10h 00m duration`

`0h 40m stop YYY (YYY)`

`Air India 112 YYY (YYY)
6:40pm Terminal: 3 flight to ZZZ (ZZZ)
8:15pm
Cabin: Economy / Coach (V)
1h 35m duration`

What should I do in such scenario? Is the airline company liable for any difference in price if I need to book another ticket?

Update: International to Domestic Transfer

Comment: Did you book these as a single ticket?

Comment: Yes, I booked it as single ticket

Comment: If airindia has changed the itinerary you should call them and ask for an alternative second flight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is truly a tight connection. Chances are that you will not make it but it is possible and the airline is gambling on it. It is possible that the flight will be early or late, depending on circumstances bit also on how the schedule is padded.

They are responsible to taking you to your final destination though. In my experience, most airlines will try to have you make the connection, so that they do not have to shuffle your booking but some it has happened to me (once) that the airline offered preemptively to book me a different connection better connection at no additional costs. Most times though, you will have to run and should you miss your connection contact customer service to arrange onward travel.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the airport and the potential immigration if 40 minutes is enough. As you redacted the airport out, this cannot be answered.

I have often done connections in under 15 minutes, it is basically walk out of the plane, walk to a gate 200 feet away, and walk in the plane. However, if you have to go walk farther, go through immigration or even security, or if you have to change terminals, it becomes nearly impossible.

Overall, it is the airlines responsibility, and they know how much time it typically takes. If the send you the changed schedule, it meann they consider it still working. If not, they will typically contact you, and offer you free rebooking to other connections, or your money back.

Comment: Sometimes the schedule is changed by one process and it takes a few days before the robot comes through and rejects the connection as impossible. Best to be proactive about it.